# Is there any way to know that Google account is associate with Microsoft account or not?

Tags: android, api, google-api, gmail

Our App is allowed to signIn with Google and Microsoft accounts. Microsoft allows a **"Gmail"** account to loggedIn into the outlook calendar.

which means,

abc@gmail.com is a Google account.
abc@gmail.com is also a Microsoft account.

so need to identify whether this Google account is associated with the Microsoft account or not.

Is there any way to find this by using Android?

Comment: @JamesZ  That's just an example. By using DNS we can identify that particular domain is in Gmail/ Microsoft whatever. For example, if a Gmail account like abc@xyz.app, for that, we can identify whether "xyz.app" is associated with the Gmail domain or Outlook, or any other domain.

Comment: Well that example is totally irrelevant and doesn't help to understand your problem at all.